# Does PyDev Eclipse console support escape characters(sequences)?

Tags: python, escaping, pydev

When I try to print

```
Good
Morning
```

I used

```
print("Good\nMorning")
```

But the result was

```
Good\nMorning
```

Does PyDev Eclipse console support escape characters (sequences)?

Comment: It works correctly for me under Windows 7 64 bit, with Eclipse Juno, PyDev 2.7.0, Python 2.7.3 and IPython 0.11

Answer (score 0):

Humm, that's weird, it's as if you're actually doing `print repr("Good\nMorning")`. Not sure why that is happening (it works as it should for me inside PyDev)...

Have you tried using the debugger to step into the print to check what's actually going on?